# UIscrollview frame Changes to super view frame?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, frame

I have three label and based on the text `contentsize` of `UIScrollview` is increasing.While I removing the `Scrollview` from super view and creating again this time frame height is increasing bottom control.

Before update:

[image]

After creating again:

[image]

Please let me know if you unclear to question.

```
-(void)setDataDynamicallyonScroll
{

    if (self.infoScroll) {
        [self.infoScroll removeFromSuperview];
        self.infoScroll = nil;
    }
    self.infoScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 55.0f, 300, 450)];
   self.infoScroll.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    UILabel *mainTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    UILabel *subTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    UILabel *detailsTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    if ([[self.dataDic valueForKey:@"subData"] valueForKey:@"FirstText"]!=nil) {
        NSString *labelText = [[self.dataDic valueForKey:@"subData"] valueForKey:@"FirstText"];
    [mainTitleLabel setText:labelText];
    // Tell the label to use an unlimited number of lines
    [mainTitleLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [mainTitleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [mainTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    mainTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:13.0/255.0 green:52.0/255.0 blue:112.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    //[infoLabel sizeToFit];
    CGSize infoLabelSize = [mainTitleLabel.text sizeWithFont:mainTitleLabel.font
                                           constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.infoScroll.frame.size.width, 9000)
                                               lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    mainTitleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, infoLabelSize.width, infoLabelSize.height);
    self.infoScroll.contentSize = infoLabelSize;
    NSLog(@"%f,%f,%f,%f ",mainTitleLabel.frame.origin.x,mainTitleLabel.frame.origin.y,mainTitleLabel.frame.size.width,mainTitleLabel.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"for First %f",self.infoScroll.contentSize.height);
    [self.infoScroll addSubview:mainTitleLabel];
}
if ([[self.dataDic valueForKey:@"subData"] valueForKey:@"MiddleText"]!=nil) {
    AppDelegate *delegate  =  (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    switch ([delegate langType]) {
        case 0:

             [subTitleLabel setText:[[[self.dataDic valueForKey:@"subData"] valueForKey:@"MiddleText"] valueForKey:@"English"]];
            break;
        case 1:

             [subTitleLabel setText:[@"\u200F" stringByAppendingString:[[[self.dataDic valueForKey:@"subData"] valueForKey:@"MiddleText"] valueForKey:@"Hebrew"]]];
            break;
        case 2:
             [subTitleLabel setText:[[[self.dataDic valueForKey:@"subData"] valueForKey:@"MiddleText"] valueForKey:@"Trans"]];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    // Tell the label to use an unlimited number of lines
    [subTitleLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [subTitleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [subTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]];
    [subTitleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
    subTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:155.0/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:16.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    //[infoLabel sizeToFit];
    CGSize infoLabelSize = [subTitleLabel.text sizeWithFont:subTitleLabel.font
                                          constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.infoScroll.frame.size.width, 9000)
                                              lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    subTitleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.infoScroll.contentSize.height+20, infoLabelSize.width, infoLabelSize.height);
    CGSize updatedScrollViewContentSize  = CGSizeMake(300,self.infoScroll.contentSize.height+infoLabelSize.height+20 );
    self.infoScroll.contentSize = updatedScrollViewContentSize;
    [self.infoScroll addSubview:subTitleLabel];
}
if ([[self.dataDic valueForKey:@"subData"] valueForKey:@"LastText"]!=nil) {
    [detailsTitleLabel setText:[[self.dataDic valueForKey:@"subData"] valueForKey:@"LastText"]];
    // Tell the label to use an unlimited number of lines
    [detailsTitleLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [detailsTitleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [detailsTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
    [detailsTitleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    detailsTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [detailsTitleLabel sizeToFit];
    CGSize infoLabelSize = [detailsTitleLabel.text sizeWithFont:detailsTitleLabel.font
                                              constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.infoScroll.frame.size.width, 9000)
                                                  lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"detailsTextbg.png"]
                                                              resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 12, 12, 12)]];
    bgView.frame = CGRectMake(0,self.infoScroll.contentSize.height+20, infoLabelSize.width, infoLabelSize.height+20);
    detailsTitleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5,10, infoLabelSize.width, infoLabelSize.height);
    CGSize updatedScrollViewContentSize  = CGSizeMake(300,self.infoScroll.contentSize.height+detailsTitleLabel.frame.size.height+50);
    self.infoScroll.contentSize = updatedScrollViewContentSize;
    [bgView addSubview:detailsTitleLabel];
    [self.infoScroll addSubview:bgView];
}

[self.view addSubview:self.infoScroll];
}
```

Comment: Put your code so we can understand your problem and can help you.

Comment: i have added the code,please check and after changing the segment control i am calling this method again.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of this line: `self.infoScroll.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;` If you are manually setting the frame, I do not believe you want it to autoResize.

Comment: but when i comment this line even though i am setting frame it is coming in same way from bottom.Thanks for reply